# День недели. Нужно определить день недели

Tags: python, python-3.x

Обозначим дни недели числами от 1 (понедельник) до 7 (воскресенье) соответственно. По известному m — дню недели первого числа текущего месяца — определите день недели числа n.

Comment: Что вы пробовали делать, что конкретно не получается?

Comment: Ничего не получается, последняя задача, которую мне нужно решить:(

Comment: Допустим у вас месяц начинается с понедельника. Тогда номер дня недели - остаток от деления исходного числа месяца на 7 (количество дней в неделе) + 1 (т.к. дни недели по условию считаются с 1, а не с 0). Чтобы то же самое для месяца начинающегося не с понедельника, нужно к исходному числу добавить номер дня недели, с которого начинается месяц (только нужно из номера дня недели, с которого начинается месяц, нужно вычесть 1).

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - читаем 100 раз. Можно больше.

Comment: Достаточно посмотреть на календарь, чтобы понять как решить эту задачу.

Comment: Не поняла, помгите

Comment: @Nastya, допустим месяц начинается с понедельника. Очевидно 3 число месяца - среда, 3+7 = 10 число тоже среда, 3 + 14 = 17 тоже среда. Идем от обратного: 17 делим на 7 - получается 2 и остаток 3. Остаток 3 означает, что 17 число - среда (правда остаток 0 означал бы воскресенье). Чтобы учитывать месяцы начинающиеся не с понедельника, нужно к исходному числу (в моем примере это 17) добавить номер дня недели, с которого начинается месяц минус 1. Для получения остатка от деления в Python нужно использовать оператор %.

Comment: Это же математика уровня третьего класса начальной школы.

Answer (score 1):

Условие написано очень сложно и непонятно. Но что я понял: Предположим m - это число 2. Число два по условию - это вторник (и по условию это первое число месяца, например, 1 ноября). Теперь нам необходимо определить день недели по числу n. Предположим, что число n = 29 (например, 29 ноября). И нам необходимо определить, какой это день недели. Соответственно, получается, т.к. сегодня 1 ноября, то до 29 ноября 28 дней. Вычислим остаток от деления по модулю 28 % 7 = 0. Таким образом, 29 ноября - это вторник (m + 0 = 2). Если бы нам нужно было бы вычислить 30 ноября, то 29 % 7 = 1. То есть (m + 1 = 3) - это была бы среда.